# merging all files into one folder from different folders

Tags: command-line, file-transfer

I want my files to be copied in one folder, the files came from different folder but in the same location.

I run this code in CMD but it copies the folder into new directory.

```
xcopy "D:\NBS Contents\Latest Images\*.jpg" "D:\output" /s
```

The latest images folder has many folders containing images files. I want to combine them into one folder.

Comment: Do you really mean `DOS` or do you mean `CMD`?

Comment: CMD rather sorry.

Comment: You may want to check [my answer to the other question](http://superuser.com/questions/180573/move-files-from-multiple-folders-all-into-parent-directory-with-command-prompt-w/226268#226268). I've made an application that does this, and it handles unexpected situations too, plus shows stats, and has some command-line niceties.

Answer (score 2):

So in `cmd` you'll to have to do the below steps

```
D:
mkdir output
cd "D:\NBS Contents\Latest Images\"
for /r %f in ( "*.jpg" ) do copy /y "%f" "D:\output"
```

Step by step explaination:

- `D:` - switches to D: drive
- `mkdir output` - Creates output directory
- `cd "D:\NBS Contents\Latest Images\"` - Changes current directory to the one in quotes
- `for /r %f in ( "*.jpg" ) do copy /y "%f" "D:\output"` - Recursively, for every jpg file, copy the source file to `d:\output`. The `/y` switch suppresses `Are you sure you want to overwrite` prompt, you can remove the switch if you want the prompt.