# script or batch move files from multiple sub directories to parent

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, automation, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [merging all files into one folder from different folders](https://superuser.com/questions/192235/merging-all-files-into-one-folder-from-different-folders)

Hello all, I have a similar issue to this post [Move files from multiple folders all into parent directory with command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/180573/move-files-from-multiple-folders-all-into-parent-directory-with-command-prompt-w)

However I have an image directory with multiple sub-directories, I'd like to move all images from the sub-directories to the root directory.

```
F:\Pictures\100KC1
F:\Pictures\100KG2
F:\Pictures\100LF1
```

and I'd like to move all the images from each sub to

```
F:\Pictures\
```

System is Win7 64-bit, I'd prefer doing it command line or batch script but if there is an app I'd accept that as well. Thanks

Comment: You say "bash" in your title. Do you have Bash available to be used to accomplish this task?

Comment: Sorry meant batch

Comment: You may want to check [my answer to the other question](http://superuser.com/questions/180573/move-files-from-multiple-folders-all-into-parent-directory-with-command-prompt-w/226268#226268). I've made an application that does this, and it handles unexpected situations too, plus shows stats, and has some command-line niceties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me like 3 seconds to Google this:

http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

You would write your `.bat` file like this:

```
xcopy f:\Pictures\100KC1 f:\Pictures /y /e
xcopy f:\Pictures\100KG2 f:\Pictures /y /e
xcopy f:\Pictures\100LF1 f:\Pictures /y /e
exit
```

This will also copy any directories in your source directories to your destination directory.

If you want to use the command line just use `&&` between each `xcopy` statement like this:

```
 xcopy f:\Pictures\100KC1 f:\Pictures /y /e && xcopy f:\Pictures\100KG2 f:\Pictures /y /e && xcopy f:\Pictures\100LF1 f:\Pictures /y /e
```

Results will be the same.