# how to move files from subfolder to parent folder?

Tags: file-transfer, music, home-directory

How do you move all files inside subfolders into the parent folder. eg: move all mp3 files inside lots of folders into parent music folder?how to do from cmd? i want the simplest and easiest way to do this. i want a short simple cmd method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [script or batch move files from multiple sub directories to parent](http://superuser.com/questions/195279/script-or-batch-move-files-from-multiple-sub-directories-to-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do it. BUT, the empty folders will not be deleted AND you need to edit the file type in the code for it to work. right now it will work only with mp3 files and. you also have to run this from the parent directory!! windows cmd only

`forfiles /s /m *.mp3 /c "cmd /c move @path %CD%"`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination .
```

It searches all subdirectories of the current folder for `.mp3` files and moves each to the current folder (`.`). You can change the filename/filter to make it work for other file types.

Compact version:

```
gci *.mp3 -R | mv -D .
```

To invoke from a normal command prompt:

```
powershell -Command "gci *.mp3 -R | mv -D ."
```

Comment: i prefer cmd version.