# win 7: copy all files from a complex folder structure to one folder

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-transfer

I have a complex folder structure similar to:

```
h:\folder1\folder2\folder3
h:\folder1\folder2\a
h:\folder1\b
h:\folder1\folder3
h:\folder1\folder4\d
```

Except with probably hundreds of folders and a depth of around 4.

I want to run a command that will `move` all the files from every sub folder into the top level folder. So something like `h:\folder1\*\*.*` to `h:\folder1`.

Is there a tool I can use to do this?  Does Windows 7 have a command that will do this?

Comment: Are you OK with doing some scripting on your own? This could easily be solved using Python or Bash scripting.

Comment: Yes I could... python might be an idea. do you have any ideas of where i would start searching for answers on how to create the python script? i assume bash won't run in windows given that it is a linux thing yes?

Comment: (...and when I say Bash, I of course mean the Windows command line... But a .bat file is very much like a Bash script anyway...)

Comment: oh right... i didn't realise. So what type of bat file script do you suggest? how would i capture all files under folders?

Comment: Found this : http://superuser.com/questions/180573/move-files-from-multiple-folders-all-into-parent-directory-with-command-prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to move all files

1. Goto the parent folder
2. Click on `Search box`
3. Type `*.*` and Wait
4. You will see all files and folders
5. Select all files except folders
6. Perform `Cut` operation (`CTRL+X`)
7. Goto to the parent folder
8. Perform `Paste` operation (`CTRL+V`)

Now files moved to parent folder

Comment: Interesting use of Windows Search ;)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [Move files from multiple folders all into parent directory with command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/180573/move-files-from-multiple-folders-all-into-parent-directory-with-command-prompt/226268#226268) .

A guy has made a command line program that works a treat within win 7, no need for extra things to install.

`h:\Downloads\MoveFilesUpFromSubfolders.exe -t .`

You just run that in the parent folder (h:\folder1) for me and then it does a test. if the test looks okay then you execute the command

`h:\Downloads\MoveFilesUpFromSubfolders.exe .`

Bam! after a couple minutes it's all done and you can delete all your folders.

Thank you guy!